# Rewrite rules for page and user profile

Tags: .htaccess

I can't figure out how to rewrite this URL

`http://localhost/site/page.php?id=[pagetitle]`

to

`http://localhost/site/page/title`

and 
for user profiles

`http://localhost/site/profile.php?username=username`

to

`http://localhost/site/profile/username`

This is the code I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?title=$1
```

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?title=$1

Comment: Can you update the question with it. It might give you a more positive score

Answer (score 1):

this will rewrite the input localhost/site/page/title to loacalhost/site/page.php?id=[pagetitle]

```
    RewriteRule ^localhost/site/(.+)$ site/page.php?id=$1
    RewriteRule ^localhost/site/profile/(.+)$ site/profile.php?username=$1
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.+)$ profile.php?username=$1 this is working for localhost/site/useranme and i want move to localhost/site/profile/username

Answer (score 0):

This should work

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?username=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?username=$1

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ page.php?title=$1
```

assumed that the .htaccess at the /site/ directory

Comment: when i use this my css cant load

Comment: @Dinho provide an example of some link. All links must be relative to the root, ie with forward slash.